# How check whether csv file with header is empty or not in perl

Tags: perl, csv, perl-module

I have a csv file `xyz.csv` with contents

```
name,age,place,phone
xyz,12,ohio,7372829
sed,23,hrh,9890908
```

I need to parse the csv file and check whether it is a empty file i.e. it doesn't have the values for the headers provided.

a null file `xyz.csv` would contain just the headers (headers no may decrease or increase)  e.g. decreased:

```
name,age,place,phone
```

increased:

```
name,age,place,mob,phno,ht
```

how do i check for a null file in below code and print whether is is null or not?

i have developed below script to parse the csv

```
open(my $data, '<', $file_c) or die "Could not open '$file_c' $!\n";

while (my $line = <$data>) 
{
    next if ($. == 1);
    chomp $line; 
    my @fields = split "," , $line; 

    print"$fields[0] fields[1]";
 }
```

Comment: You could use a scalar to represent the first line of the file and check if it is defined.  However this does advance the filehandle and the rest of your reading will be from the second line on.

Comment: @squiguy...how do i do that.....i jus want to skip the header and check next line is null or has any values...can pls advise

Comment: You can check if it only contains a newline character or if it is blank. last if not defined $line; last if $line eq "\n";

Comment: pen(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

while (my $line = <$data>) {  
next if ($. == 1);
my @fields = split "," , $line; 
print "\n ***** @fields";
if(@fields eq " \n"){
           print "empty file";
           }      its not printng empty file...can you pls chck

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the range operator search for any lines that aren't the first line.  This should be pretty efficient:

```
while (<$data>) 
{
  unless (1..1) { print "not null\n"; exit 0; }
}
print "null\n";
exit 1;
```

Or you could just pluck the lines off one by one - if the second is defined, then it's not null:

```
<$data>;
print (defined <$data> ? "not null" : "null");
```

Comment: Will print "not null" if all lines beyond the header are only \n

Comment: In fact, if even the first one is.  RFC4180 states that all lines should have the same number of fields, but the OQ did not specify field number checking, so it's reasonable to read should as 'not must' in which case a blank row is not null.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I'd look into one of the CSV handling CPAN modules, e.g. `Text::CSV`, `Tie::CSV_File` or `DBD::CSV`.

To check if the file is empty would be a simple case of counting the number of parsed lines in the file. With `DBI` and `DBD::CSV` you could use a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name` SQL statement.

The following link provides a quick tutorial on parsing CSV files with perl: http://perlmeme.org/tutorials/parsing_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

You cound any how check for the number of lines and if you are sure that alwys the header is present.then the first line is always the header.

so if line 2 is not present or length of line2 is 0 then its an empty file.

Comment: @sarathi...am new to perl...can you pls help me witha sample script for the same check...

Answer (score 0):

This should work.From your shell prompt check whether `wc -l < FNAME` returns only line cnt.

```
print "empty" if chomp(my $dummy = `wc -l < FNAME`) == 1;
```

*It may be in-efficient, though.*